# Изменение ToolBar Activity из Fragment

Tags: android

У меня есть toolbar к которому привязана навигация, в одном из фрагментов я хочу сделать вот [[Это][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaKoR.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaKoR.jpg). Вот что я пытался сделать.
Activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

Fragment:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainappbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/maincollapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainbackdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder_book"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="test"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                /> 
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Но у меня получается вот[[Это][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRmg2.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRmg2.jpg) и [[это][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28j0F.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28j0F.jpg). Что мне нужно изменить ? или где прочесть ?

Comment: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` для этой активити в манифесте

Comment: @AndreyMihalev А как же будут работать Bar в других фрагментах? Активити только одно. Мне нужно как то сделать в нем изменения

Comment: Можно использовать для этого интерфейс между фрагментом и активностью, из нужного вам фрагмента шлите информацию в активность по поводу изменения тулбара

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko а что нужно изменять ?  Я не могу понять, как в активность добавить новый элемент, так в добавок этим элементом ещё и тулбар завернуть

Comment: @ЕгорГлухов, ну скорее всего менять подход к навигации. Если у вас уже есть тулбар, может только его и оставить, остальное реализовать иначе?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev да, Я реализовал по другом, получилось прекрасно. Как я понял, что бы провернуть то что я хотел, нужно иметь отдельно тул бар и изменять его через код.Это слишком затратно и не правильно. Спасибо за помощь.